# Typescript can't find class in the same module

Tags: typescript

I got two classes in the same scope and an angular controller. But when trying to created Class2 in the angular controller it doesn't recognize my constructor or in fact it doesnt recognize the class at all `console.log(m.Class2) = undefined`. Is this a typescript bug or am I missing something? I'm using VS2015 and intellisensi can find the class, but after compiling it and running it on chrome I get the error message: `'m.Class2 is not a constructor'`.

```
  module m {
        export class Class1{
          constructor(protected id: number) {
          }
        }

        export class Class2{
          constructor(protected id: number) {        
          }
        }


        angular.module("test").controller("mopstest.controller", ['$scope', function ($scope: any) {
            let c = new m.Class1(1); //works
            let b = new m.Class2(1); //error m.Class2 is not a constructor
            console.log(m.Class1); //function Class1(id)....
            console.log(m.Class2); //undefined
        }]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted

```
module m {
        export class Class1{
          constructor(protected id: number) {
          }
        }

        export class Class2{
          constructor(protected id: number) {        
          }
        }


        angular.module("test").controller("mopstest.controller", ['$scope', function ($scope: any) {
            let c = new m.Class1(1); //works
            let b = new m.Class2(1); //error m.Class2 is not a constructor
            console.log(m.Class1); //function Class1(id)....
            console.log(m.Class2); //undefined
        }]);
    }
```

Will **definitely work** unless `m` is also declared elsewhere, or you have your module split across multiple files (more on this https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/tips/outFile.md)

Comment: Yes, each class and the controller are in different files but are using module m.

Comment: If they are in different files then ordering matters. Use external modules please (not `module`). See https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/tips/outFile.md

Comment: I've read that page several times but I can't seem to understand, care to explain?

Comment: I'm by the way using bundling the .js files that comes from the .ts files into one single file.